# running perl scripts on folder within folder

Tags: perl, batch-file

I have 4 Perl scripts and i run them through batch file to run on each file

Scripts.bat

```
perl script1.pl %1
perl script2.pl %1
perl script3.pl %1
perl script4.pl %1
```

Then to run it in a given folder i use the perl command(here %1 is where folder name is passed)

```
perl -le "-f and print and `scripts.bat $_` for map <$_\\*>, pop||'.'" %1
```

But this works on only folder in 1st level .

I need to make it run through folder recursive(folder within folder). It can have more than 2 levels of folder within folder also.

Like if

```
abc(folder) > xyz(folder) > file4.c, file5.c, file6.c
            > file1.c
            > file2.c
            > file3.c
```

It should run on all files.

Any kind of help is welcome, be it some perl script or one liner perl command or batch file

Comment: See [File::Find](http://p3rl.org/File::Find).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From batch file:

```
for /r "c:\abc" %%f in (*.c) do call "scripts.bat" "%%f"
```

To run it from command line, replace `%%f` with `%f`

Comment: @Ad-vic: Just an example, as it seems bad asummed from your samples. What it does is enumerate all the `*.c` files under `c:\abc` and calls `"scripts.bat"` with the full name of file (with path) as parameter. Replace `"c:\abc"` with the root directory from where to start to search files, or if it is the same directory as the commandline/batch file replace with `"."`.

Comment: thanks !! works fine. I used "%1" instead of "C:\abc" so that i could pass folder name through argument

Comment: you made it look so simple.just a 'for' '/r for recursive' and 'call'.